# (Javascript / jQuery) Target a div with a p with a specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm struggeling for hours now how to target a div that contains a p with a specifict text

HTML

```
<div class="NavBar_Row_Button2"><p>DONATE</p></div>
<div class="NavBar_Row_Button2"><p>CONTACT</p></div>
<img src="Design/Erk%20logo.png" alt="Erk Logo" id="NavBar_Logo">
<img src="Design/ycoGM9dcE.png" id="Drop_Menu">
```

Jquery'

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.NavBar_Row_Button2 P').hover(function(){
    $(this).css('color', '#00ddcb'); 
    $(this.parentElement).css('background-color', '#00ddcb');    
  });

  $('.NavBar_Row_Button2 P').mouseleave(function(){
      $(this).css('color', 'white'); 
      $(this.parentElement).css('background-color', 'white');
  });

  $('.NavBar_Row_Button1 P').hover(function(){
      $(this).css('color', '#00ddcb'); 
      $(this.parentElement).css('background-color', '#00ddcb');
  });
  $('.NavBar_Row_Button1 P').mouseleave(function(){
      $(this).css('color', 'white'); 
      $(this.parentElement).css('background-color', 'white');
  });
  if ($(this).is('div:contains("HEY")')) {
      alert('right')  
  };
});
```

So als you can See I change some background colors but I also want to to something with an image if an spefic div with a p with a spefic text is :hover
how can I target this spefic object and in this case this is the div with the

DONATE

tried things like contain and other stuff but wont work for me

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.NavBar_Row_Button2 P').hover(function(){
    if($(this).text() == 'Text you are looking for')
    {
      $(this).css('color', '#00ddcb'); 
      $(this.parentElement).css('background-color', '#00ddcb');
    }
});
```

Comment: THANKS YOU SO MUCH ! it works! also thanks for your fast response :D

Comment: If this solution works for you, remember to mark it as the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `:contains()` selector:

```
$('.NavBar_Row_Button2 p:contains("DONATE")').hover(function(){
    $(this).css({'color': 'red'});
});
```

However, I might recommend that you try to use some other method of identification in order to separate the textual content from the behavior, such as adding a class or other attribute to identify the target.

Answer (score 0):

Since it doesn't look like you are generating your text dynamically for these `<p>` elements, why don't you just give them each a unique id and select that way? Something like:

HTML:

```
<div class="NavBar_Row_Button2">
   <p id="donate">DONATE</p>
 </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#donate').hover(function() {
 //Whatever you want to do here
});
```